# ¿Como hacer que carguen distintas vistas en el archivo index.html, jquery?

Tags: jquery

no se si de esa forma se realiza esta pregunta.
Actualmente tengo un archivo index.html donde tengo todo el css y todo el js necesario para el diseño pero tengo una carpeta llamada "vistas" y basicamente para que el diseño, en estos nuevos archivos que se encuentran en la carpeta vista se muetren debo de igual forma importar todo el css y js necesario, es decir hacer la misma configuracion del index.html.
Lo que necesito es que cuando yo ingrese a una vista, por ejemplo a **"pagina 1"** se vaya cargando en el div "page-content" que se encuentra en el index.html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

```
    <title>Titulo</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/skin.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/framework.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/ionicons.min.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic,900,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/plugins.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/custom.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page-transitions">

        <div class="page-preloader page-preloader-dark">
            <div class="spinner"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="header header-light">
            <a href="index.html" class="header-logo">PMT <span class="color-red-dark">S.A</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="header-icon header-icon-1 close-sidebar-mask"></a>
            <a href="#" class="header-icon header-icon-1 open-sidebar">
                <em class="line-1"></em>
                <em class="line-2"></em>
                <em class="line-3"></em>    
            </a>
        </div>

        <!-- Main Small Icon Sidebar -->
        <div class="sidebar-menu sidebar-light">
            <div class="sidebar-menu-scroll">
                <a class="current-menu" href="index.html"><i class="ion-ios-star-outline"></i><em>Apoyo</em></a>       
                <a data-submenus="sub1" href="#"><i class="ion-ios-home-outline"></i><em>Inicio</em></a>       
                <a data-submenus="sub2" href="#"><i class="ion-ios-gear-outline"></i><em>Mas</em></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Home Submenus -->
        <div class="submenu submenu-light" id="sub1">
            <div class="submenu-scroll">
                <a class="close-sidebar" href="#"><i class="ion-ios-close-empty"></i><em>Cerrar</em></a>        
                <a href="index.html"><i class="ion-ios-star-outline"></i><em>Pagina 1</em></a>       
                <a href="index-classic.html"><i class="ion-ios-home-outline"></i><em>Pagina 2</em></a>  
                <a href="index-classic.html"><i class="ion-ios-home-outline"></i><em>Pagina 3</em></a>  
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Features Submenus -->
        <div class="submenu submenu-light" id="sub2">
            <div class="submenu-scroll">
                <a class="close-sidebar" href="#"><i class="ion-ios-close-empty"></i><em>Cerrar</em></a>        
                <a href="features-tabs.html"><i class="ion-ios-more-outline"></i><em>Información</em></a>       
                <a href="features-toggles.html"><i class="ion-ios-toggle-outline"></i><em>Cerrar Sesión</em></a>
            </div>
        </div>    

        <div id="page-content" class="header-clear-large">
            <div id="page-content-scroll"><!--Enables this element to be scrolled -->
                <div class="content">
                    <img data-original="images/1.png" alt="img" class="preload-image responsive-image full-bottom" src="images/empty.png" >
                    <h2 class="center-text thiner half-bottom">Esto es la pagina principal</h2>
                    <p class="center-boxed-text center-text half-bottom">

                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="decoration decoration-margins"></div>

                <div class="footer footer-dark">
                    <a href="index.html" class="footer-logo scale-hover"></a>
                    <p>

                    </p>
                    <div class="decoration"></div>
                    <p class="copyright-text"> |<span id="copyright-year"></span>..</p>
                </div>
            </div>   
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="back-to-top-badge"><i class="ion-android-arrow-dropup"></i>Volver arriba</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Script - Controladores -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/controllers/login.js"></script>
    <!---------------------------->
</body>
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Haz intentado usar un iframe? por que un iframe? el iframe permite crear un marco donde cargue una vista sin interferir sus scripts porpios con el del padre osea el index.html, si esa pagina 1 tiene sus propios scripts o css puede interferir con el del index.html por eso se maneja un iframe, nose que te parece la idea?

Comment: Soy nuevo en ese tema, la verdad no tengo idea como se implementaría.

Comment: La idea seria crear una capa que tenga como contenido un iframe, el iframe tiene como atributo el src donde indicas la ruta de la vista o el html que quieres mostrar, cuando le des click a un menu obtienes la url asociada a ese menu en el evento click y se lo seteas al iframe y asi cada vez que le des a cualquier menu puedas ver su contenido dinamicamente en index.html sin interferir con este.

Comment: Hola @DavidLeonardoMolinaRuizDav Los iframes deben ser evitados, sobre todo si hay alternativas (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362730/are-iframes-considered-bad-practice). No debería haber interferencias desde el momento en el que las dos páginas son del sitio y pueden ser programadas en consecuencia. Una pregunta para JG_JG, ¿deseas hacer una especie de single page application? (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) La wikipedia es una fuente que prefiero evitar, pero bueno para hacerme entender bastará  esta vez :).

Comment: Exacto Roberto Pintos Lopez, desconocia que se le llamaba Single Page Application. Pero es asi como quiero trabajarlo.